# Is OpenVPN UDP vulnerable to heartbleed?

Tags: openvpn, udp, heartbleed

Is OpenVPN UDP vulnerable to heartbleed?

I need to decide if I'm going to rebuild some servers, but they are very carefully firewalled; 1194/TCP is one of the firewalled ports (yay whitelist!).

1194/UDP is used (mission critical).

Answer (score 6):

OpenVPN over UDP also uses TLS, so it is equally effected just like HTTPS. I have verified this by looking at a packet capture, and [saw that the Heartbeat extension is advertised](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/55254/2630).

Many public tools just check for TLS/STARTTLS servers, but there is no reason why someone cannot craft a special tool for OpenVPN.

The TLS layer in OpenVPN runs on a proprietary socket layer which runs atop of UDP/TCP as can be seen in [this picture](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/attachment/wiki/RoadMap/openvpn-3.0.png).

Comment: And no proof that someone hasn't already crafted such a tool.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, OpenVPN derives its encryption entirely from OpenSSL.  The OpenVPN community has posted a response to Heartbleed:  https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/heartbleed